# passing variables between scenes using JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

I tried almost every available solution but nothing seems to work I need to pass a `string` between 2 Javafx scenes, but when I click to navigate to the next scene nothing happens. here's my code so far:

```
String myVariable = "test";
FXMLLoader loader =new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Comments.fxml"));
Parent root = null;
CommentsController commentsController = new CommentsController();
commentsController = loader.getController();
commentsController.transferMessage(myVariable);
 Stage stage = new Stage();
 stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
 stage.show();
```

PS: I have `transferMessage()` method set-up in the second scene.

Comment: There should be a `NullPointerException` happening. The `controller` property of the loader as well as `root` remain `null`, since you never call `load()` or assign a different value to `root`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. surround your chunk of code with a `try{}...catch(IOException ex){}`
2. replace `Parent root = null` with `Parent root = load.loader()`

That's all it takes

Comment: Preferrably the initial assignment to the `commentsController` variable should also be removed to avoid creating an instance of the controller that isn't used...